# Can I let test users skip logging into PayPal sandbox?

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using the PayPal sandbox to test user transaction on my website.

The site is going to be put through usability testing soon.

The problem is, whenever a user goes to complete a transaction, they are first asked to "Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features."

This is the link that my form points to: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

I want the test users to skip having to create a PayPal sandbox account and just use the test user accounts that I have setup.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. A user has to have a developer account created at developer.paypal.com to be able to use any PayPal hosted payment methods on the sandbox.

However, you can submit API calls to the sandbox without the members needing a developer.paypal.com sandbox account.